# What is the reason for missing external template files while generating a new component in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

I am currently working on a angular 5 project based on metronic admin template.

I generated a component using "ng generate component" command.But it generated only the component.ts file.There is no template file.what is the reason?

syntax used for generating the component

**ng generate component users**

This is my component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  template: `
    <p>
      users works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

If I create a fresh angular project and generates a component,the template file is also generating.But for the current project, only component.ts file is generating.

My local angular-cli version is 1.6.6 and global version is 1.6.8.

Comment: Check the root inside .angular-cli.json.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya root is src..

Comment: Can you add the exact syntax that you're using to generate the component?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya Hi I updated the question with the syntax.please check it.

Comment: What's the templateUrl in your component class? Maybe it has generated inline template.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya Yes it generated inline template.But why it is not generating a new template file.For a fresh angular project it is generating all files.Only for this project problem is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined defaults in template generation to inline in the `.angular-cli.json` file.

Change the below to false:

```
"defaults": {
    "inlineTemplate": false
  }
```

Refer below for more info

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli

Comment: in the latest version of angular this fille be in the name of angular.json